# How to exit from cv2.setMouseCallback function of one image within multiple images and execute the ahead code of it?

Tags: python, opencv, callback, mouseevent

**WHAT I'M TRYING TO DO?**
I am trying to select the cordinates points on mouse click using `cv2.setMouseCallback()` function and printing the cordinates of every mouse click. I have put on the condition that the cordinates will be printed only until the counter and counterm is less than equal to 5 for two different functons, namely `clickEventCTscanImage(event, x, y, flags, param)` and `clickEventMRIscanImage(event, x, y, flags, param)`respectively.

**WHAT I WANT TO ACHIEVE?**
I want to achieve that when I have selected the 5 points in totall the specific image should get closed and the second image should get automatically open ups and asks to perform the same function. that means the CT Scan image after achieving 5 points should get closed automatically and MRI image should open up for selecting the points and on selecting the points it should also get closed and then further code should executed

**WHAT IS THE PROBLEM?**
So, based on what I have described above. When I tries to add "return" in the else condition of `clickEventCTscanImage(event, x, y, flags, param)` and `clickEventMRIscanImage(event, x, y, flags, param)` function, the windows doesn't get closed and the code doesn't execute further
also if I add `cv2.destroyAllWindows()` in the else condition then the CT Scan image gets clos but the MRI image doesn't opens up.

**CODE SNIPPET**

```py
#importing libraries

import argparse
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cm as cm 
import cv2
import imageio
import scipy.ndimage as ndi
import os
from PIL import Image


global CTscanImageCordinates
CTscanImageCordinates = []

global MRIscanImageCordinates
MRIscanImageCordinates = []

counter = 1

# Define Click Function for CT Scan
def clickEventCTscanImage(event, x, y, flags, param):
    global counter

    if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
        if counter <= 5:
            print(x,y)
            CTscanImageCordinates.append([x,y])
            print("hi")
            counter = counter + 1
        else:
            cv2.destroyAllWindows()

counterm = 1

# Define Click Function for CT Scan
def clickEventMRIscanImage(event, x, y, flags, param):
    global counterm

    if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
        if counterm <= 5:
            print(x,y)
            MRIscanImageCordinates.append([x,y])
            print("hi")
            counterm = counterm + 1
        else:
            cv2.destroyAllWindows()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    arg = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    arg.add_argument("--pathInCTImage", help="Path to CT Scan Image")
    arg.add_argument("--pathInMRIImage", help="Path to MRI Scan Image")
    args = arg.parse_args()

    CTscanImage = cv2.imread(args.pathInCTImage)
    MRIscanImage = cv2.imread(args.pathInMRIImage) #MRI Image will be registered

    cv2.imshow('CT Scan Image', CTscanImage)
    cv2.setMouseCallback('CT Scan Image', clickEventCTscanImage)
    cv2.waitKey()

    cv2.imshow('MRI Scan Image', MRIscanImage)
    cv2.setMouseCallback('MRI Scan Image', clickEventMRIscanImage)
    cv2.waitKey()
```

Please help me in this. Thanks and Regards

I tried using `return` statement as well as the `cv2.destroyAllWindows()` statement for moving out of the image window after selecting the points but none of them worked for me.

Comment: don't make GUIs with OpenCV. it is for computer vision, not for making GUIs. use a proper GUI toolkit.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz I agree, but I still answered as the OP seems new to Python. And classes are an important concept he needs to know, I presume.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz Can you please look into my comments and answer discussion below?

Answer (score 0):

## Solution

```py
import argparse
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cm as cm 
import cv2
import imageio
import scipy.ndimage as ndi
import os
from PIL import Image


class GetCoordsMRICT:
    def __init__(self, CTscanImage, MRIscanImage):
        self.counter = 0
        self.counterm = 0
        self.CTScanCoords = []
        self.MRIScanCoords = []
        # Running the Functions as follows,

        cv2.imshow('CT Scan Image', CTscanImage)
        cv2.setMouseCallback('CT Scan Image', self.clickEventCTscanImage)
        cv2.waitKey()
        cv2.imshow('MRI Scan Image', MRIscanImage)
        cv2.setMouseCallback('MRI Scan Image', self.clickEventMRIscanImage)
        cv2.waitKey()

    def clickEventCTscanImage(self, event, x, y, flags, param):
        if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
            if self.counter <= 5:
                print(x,y)
                self.CTScanCoords.append([x,y])
                self.counter = self.counter + 1
            
        if self.counter == 5:
            print('[+] CT Scan Points Completed.')
            cv2.destroyAllWindows()
            return 0

        # Define Click Function for CT Scan
    def clickEventMRIscanImage(self, event, x, y, flags, param):
        if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
            if self.counterm <= 5:
                print(x,y)
                self.MRIScanCoords.append([x,y])
                self.counterm = self.counterm + 1
        if self.counterm == 5:
            print('[+] MRI Scan Points Completed.')
            cv2.destroyAllWindows()
            return 0


if __name__ == "__main__":

    arg = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    arg.add_argument("--ct", help="Path to CT Scan Image")
    arg.add_argument("--mr", help="Path to MRI Scan Image")
    args = arg.parse_args()


    CTscanImage = cv2.imread(args.ct)
    MRIscanImage = cv2.imread(args.mr) #MRI Image will be registered

    handler = GetCoordsMRICT(CTscanImage, MRIscanImage)

    print(f'[+] CT Scan Codes: {handler.CTScanCoords}')
    print(f'[+] MRI Scan Codes: {handler.MRIScanCoords}')
```

I recommend using classes in python and below is the code to get the co-ordinates. The following class returns the five require co-ordinates as a list.

### Output

[image]

### Refrence

https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html

Comment: It is only showing till CT Scan image. For MRI images it is just getting stiuck at CT image only and not showing even MRI image as well. Can you please let me know that how can that be possible it cn show the MRI image?

Comment: ahmed khurram can you please let me know?

Comment: @Jaskirat Which OS and OpenCV version are you on, I am using `opencv-contrib-python 4.6.6` on Windows 11.

Comment: I tried your code only initially. According to your code after I selects the points on CT image, then it automatically gets close and I'm unable to select points from MRI image

Comment: Even after running your code the issue is same which has been described here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74802788/unable-to-rectify-the-code-and-execute-to-achieve-desired-output Can you please help me resolve that?

Comment: @Jaskirat please create a GitHub discussion where we can go ahead and fix the issue and then add the correct code here that works on your end.

Comment: @Jaskirat https://github.com/OttomanZ/Jaskerit/issues/1

Comment: I have created the discussion here as a gist - https://gist.github.com/jaskiratsingh2000/3d5193a978d5ee29f93d5d2e42954317

Comment: I have created the gist link above can you please check now and help me

Comment: @Jaskirat I have added the required solution please confirm on GitHub